# Jaws Chrome - on tab focus on button announcing lot other information

Tags: html, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

When we do tab focus on edit button, it is announcing lot other information including job title, description and aria-label of others button that are check and cross and other issue when we focus on "check" or "cross" button then it is announcing whole things here including title, description and buttons it is only happening when we are keeping role="table", on other hand it is working as expected in NVDA and Firefox".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            button{
            width: 50px;
            height: 20px;
            }
            input{
            display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div role="table">
            <div
                role="row"
                >
                <div
                    role="columnheader"
                    class="g-col-3 h3"
                    >
                    Alert title
                </div>
                <div
                    data-ph-at-id="email-frequency-text"
                    role="columnheader"
                    >
                    Frequency
                </div>
                <div
                    role="columnheader"
                    >
                    Actions
                </div>
                <div
                    role="columnheader"
                    class="g-col-3 h3"
                    >
                    Date Subscribed
                </div>
            </div>
            <div
                class="phw-grid phw-pt-6 phw-pb-6 phw-align-items-center"
                role="row"
                >
                <div
                    class="result-block g-col-3 g-col-md-12 phw-form-group"
                    role="cell"
                    >
                    <div
                        class="jobTitle ph-a11y-jobTitleName phw-input-group"
                        >
                        <div
                            >
                            Chime Jobs
                        </div>
                        <button
                            aria-label="Edit Chime jobs"
                            tabindex="0"
                            role="button"
                            >
                        edit
                        </button>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            data-ph-at-id="update-job-title-input"
                            data-ps="8be1e0cd-input-1"
                            aria-label="job alert title"
                            />
                        <button
                            aria-label="Save"
                            role="button"
                            data-ph-at-id="submit-updated-job-title-button"
                            data-ph-component-name="save-button"
                            data-ps="8be1e0cd-button-2"
                            >
                        Check
                        </button>
                        <button
                            aria-label="Cancel"
                            role="button"
                            key-role="btnRole"
                            >
                        cross
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div
                        class="jobOtherInfo"
                        data-ph-at-id="job-other-info-block"
                        >
                        <span
                            class="p3"
                            >title discription</span
                            >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div
                    class="result-block g-col-3 g-col-md-12"
                    role="cell"
                    data-ps="8be1e0cd-div-22"
                    >
                    <div
                        >
                        <select
                            aria-label="frequency"
                            data-ph-at-id="mail-freq-drp-dwn"
                            class="phw-form-select"
                            >
                            <option
                                data-ph-at-id="mail-freq-drp-dwn-opt"
                                data-ps="8be1e0cd-option-1"
                                >
                                Frequency option
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div
                    class="g-col-3 g-col-md-12"
                    role="cell"
                    :class="$style['actions-date']"
                    data-ps="8be1e0cd-div-24"
                    >
                    <span 
                        ><a
                        aria-label="View Results "
                        class="phw-link"
                        data-ps="8be1e0cd-a-1"
                        >
                    view results
                    </a></span
                        >
                    <span
                        data-ps="8be1e0cd-span-4"
                        ><a
                        role="button"
                        href="javascript:void(0)"
                        class="phw-link"
                        aria-label="unsubscribe"
                        >
                    unsubscribe
                    </a></span
                        >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```